# Difference between the following two ways to do automatic dependency generation

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am reading *Managing Projects with GNU Make* and in chapter 2, the author writes the following way to do automatic dependency generation

```
depend: count_words.c lexer.c counter.c
       $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $^ > $@

include depend
```

However, I usually do

```
makedepend -I $(CC) -f $(MAKEFILE) count_words.c lexer.c counter.c
```

I am not sure which way is better or they are serving equivalent purpose and can be use interchangeably?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any difference between the two, although I suppose the first means you need one less tool for your build so it's marginally better.

That said, an even better method is to add [`-MMD -MP`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) to your preprocessor flags when compiling, which generates the dependency files as a side effect of compilation itself.

```
SRCS := count_words.c lexer.c counter.c
OBJS := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEPS := $(SRC:.c=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP

$(OBJS):

-include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You get the happy situation of dependencies for free, and they are never out of date.